# Lost SSL in Iframe

Tags: php, iframe, ssl, xajax

i have a problem with an application which is runs in a browser like firefox or ie.
When i trying to put this application in a frame, it doesn't work

Im using xajax to check a number and if the number is allowed - some content will be changed with inner html. This works fine as long as I open the application directly in a browser.

But it doesn't work in a frame.

I find out, that the xajax.config.requestURI changed in the frame from https to http.

directly:

```
try { if (undefined == xajax.config) xajax.config = {}; } catch (e) { xajax = {};
xajax.config = {}; };
xajax.config.requestURI = "https://....../yx.php";
xajax.config.statusMessages = false;
xajax.config.waitCursor = true;
xajax.config.version = "xajax 0.5";
xajax.config.legacy = false;
xajax.config.defaultMode = "asynchronous";
xajax.config.defaultMethod = "POST";
```

with iframe:

```
try { if (undefined == xajax.config) xajax.config = {}; } catch (e) { xajax = {};
xajax.config = {}; };
xajax.config.requestURI = "http://........./yx.php";
xajax.config.statusMessages = false;
xajax.config.waitCursor = true;
xajax.config.version = "xajax 0.5";
xajax.config.legacy = false;
xajax.config.defaultMode = "asynchronous";
xajax.config.defaultMethod = "POST";
```

I hope, someone can help me

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you may be experiencing cross domain/protocol problems, having to do with the same origin policy as dictated by the browser. Please reference these other QA's to see if they may help:

[Ajax using https on an http page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105934/ajax-using-https-on-an-http-page)
[jQuery ajax and SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418620/jquery-ajax-and-ssl)
[Can Ajax HTTP and HTTPS work side by side?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841479/can-ajax-http-and-https-work-side-by-side)
[How do I send a cross-domain POST request via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript)